# How can i get layout from custom helper with zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, helper

I need to get layout in my custom helper with zend framework 2.
How can i do this?

```
class CategoryHelper extends AbstractHelper
{

   public function getCatMenu(){
       $this->getView()->layout(); //this not works, how can i get view's layout
  }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on *why* you need the layout. What's the end goal?

Comment: because my layout hold "all_categories" array as a variable ($layout->cats). i need it every  page.

Comment: If you need it in "every" page I would go along and add those to the layout within the module.php onBootstrap method.

Answer (score 1):

`$this->getView()->getEvent()->getRenderer()->layout()`

Maybe a best way to would be to create a factory and then inject the layout into your helper.

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/View.php

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php

Comment: +1 "create a factory and then inject the layout into your helper."